# SQL Query with Alias and Re-use it. How does it work?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have some query that using alias 'as' for example:

```
select (TABLE_A.NAME) as NAME_A from TABLE_B where id = 1
```

What I am trying to do is re-call/re-use the `NAME_A` as next column like:

```
select (TABLE_A.NAME) as NAME_A, (NAME_A+"ME") as NAME_B from TABLE_B where id = 1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I guess you cannot. Btw, `(NAME_A+"ME") ` are you trying to concatenate ?

Comment: that's is just for example.. the point is i just want to re-call the NAME_A for next column

Comment: @Diastowo . . . No, you cannot re-use a column alias in the same `select` (nor in the `from` nor `where`).  Use a subquery or CTE for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference a select list alias in the same select list. As MySQL documentation on [select list aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) says:

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

You need to wrap the aliased select expression into a subquery and you can use the aliased expression in the outer query. Or just simply refer to the field under its original name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery instead. A workaround would be something like:

```
select NAME_A, (NAME_A+"ME") as NAME_B
from(
    select (TABLE_A.NAME) as NAME_A
    from TABLE_A
        where id = 1
    )
```